# Save lapply output as data frame loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, apply, lapply

I have the following data in R:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
city var value
a   var1    0.19
b   var1    0.67
c   var1    0.19
a   var2    0.14
b   var2    0.38
c   var2    0.27
a   var3    0.59
b   var3    0.42
c   var3    0.27
a   var4    0.28
b   var4    0.37
c   var4    0.91
", header=TRUE)
```

I need to create different data frames of city b with the rest of the cities (e.g. city b with city a, city b with city c, etc.). Andrie managed to get that with the `lapply` function.

```
lapply(
  setdiff(levels(dat$city), "b"),
  function(i){
    ret <- dat[dat$city %in% c("b", i), ]
    ret[order(ret$var, ret$city), ]
  })
```

Then I get the output I need, but I do not know how to save each of the [[i]] as a different dataframe. Eg. [[1]] would be citybcitya, [[2]] would be citybcityc, etc.

```
[[1]]
   city  var value
2     b var1  0.67
1     a var1  0.19
5     b var2  0.38
4     a var2  0.14
8     b var3  0.42
7     a var3  0.59
11    b var4  0.37
10    a var4  0.28

[[2]]
   city  var value
2     b var1  0.67
3     c var1  0.19
5     b var2  0.38
6     c var2  0.27
8     b var3  0.42
9     c var3  0.27
11    b var4  0.37
12    c var4  0.91
```

How can I achieve it without the for loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `list2env`, you''ll need to save your `lapply` results first and then give names to the list objects:

```
temp <- lapply(
  setdiff(levels(dat$city), "b"),
  function(i){
    ret <- dat[dat$city %in% c("b", i), ]
    ret[order(ret$var, ret$city), ]
  })

names(temp) <- c("citybcitya", "citybcityc")
list2env(temp, envir = .GlobalEnv)

citybcitya
#    city  var value
# 1     a var1  0.19
# 2     b var1  0.67
# 4     a var2  0.14
# 5     b var2  0.38
# 7     a var3  0.59
# 8     b var3  0.42
# 10    a var4  0.28
# 11    b var4  0.37

citybcityc
# city  var value
# 2     b var1  0.67
# 3     c var1  0.19
# 5     b var2  0.38
# 6     c var2  0.27
# 8     b var3  0.42
# 9     c var3  0.27
# 11    b var4  0.37
# 12    c var4  0.91
```